# The Impact of Singletons on Some Basic Measure Theory Computations

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal S, \mu)$ be a measure space where $X=[0, 1], \mathcal S$ is the set of all Borel subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

I have two related questions:

1. As part of a larger proof, I am trying to show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\; x \in [0, 1]$ is Borel measurable. Of course, $f$ is monotonically increasing on $(0, 1]$, so it is Borel-measurable on $(0, 1]$. $f$ is not defined at $x=0$, so I am not sure how that show that $f$ is Borel measurable on $\{0\}$ as well. Now, $\{0\}$ is a closed set, and $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is also a singleton and hence a closed set. So, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a Borel set, which implies that $f$ is indeed Borel-measurable on the entire $X$. Is this reasoning correct?
2. Suppose we are asked to find the Lebesgue integral of some Borel-measurable function $f$ over the set $[0, 1]$, that is $\int_{[0, 1]} f = p$ where $p\in\mathbb R$. Suppose further that we successfully find the Lebesgue integral of $f$ over $(0, 1)$, that is $\int_{(0, 1)} f = q$ where $q\in\mathbb R$. Roughly speaking, thinking in terms of Riemann integrals, we would have $p=q$ because the area of a function under a single point is $0$. Does $p=q$ hold when computing Lebesgue integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT an answer/ A long comment:

Does $p=q$ even when computing  Lebesgue integrals? Yes. More generally, if A and B are two Lebesgue measurable sets such $A= B \cup N$ for some Lebesgue null set $N,$ then for any Lebesgue measurable function $f,$ we have $ \int_A f = \int_B f.$

For question#1, are you defining $f(0)= 0$? I think the natural choice would be $f(0) = +\infty.$ In that case you're dealing with extended real numbers, but that's okay. If you do that, then $f$ would be Borel measurable on $[0, 1].$ Note that implicity, I am using the fact that if two functions are equal to each other ae, then the measurability of one implies the measurability of the other one. So, you could define anything for $f(0).$ So, you're correct.

Comment: #1 makes perfect sense, thanks! For #2, is there a typo in the first line of your response?

Comment: Could you tell me what was that?

Comment: "Does $p=q$ even [...] when computing Lebesgue integrals?" Did you forget to type something where I put in the [...]? I don't think you mean to use the word "even" as a verb here, do you?

Comment: Basically, I copied this sentence from your problem statement. It's the last sentence of your post. By the way, I think I need to include a simple fact: I said the two integrals are equal for Lebesgue measurable sets. In particular, it's true for Borel measurable sets. So, if you working with Borel measurable sets, you're good.

Comment: Ah, that was a typo in my post. Fixed now! Thanks for the info!